# "Unsupported Build Type" when building a project with qmake

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I try to compile QGroundControl source code. QT is installed. and edit the path on Win8

http://www.qgroundcontrol.org/dev/build_source#build_from_source

```
cd C:\mav\qgroundcontrol 
qmake -tp vc qgroundcontrol.pro
```

When I try to build project, it gives error.

```
Project MESSAGE : Qt version 5.2.1
Project ERROR : Unsupported build type
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: @LaszloPapp is the local qt guru here, maybe he see this and helps.

Comment: Well I couldn't find any note on the QGroundControl Website whether they are supporting Qt5+. They are using [Qt 4.7/4.8](http://www.qgroundcontrol.org/dev/build_source#build_from_source), so maybe you can't do anything but using an older Qt version.

Comment: @lifetime: have you tried a clean build, too? Which msvc or mingw version are you using?

Comment: @LaszloPapp mingw version is 4.8 , I didn't clean build. How can I do that. nmake command is not working. Maybe I should install older version of QT as Bowdzone says. I'll try now.

Comment: @lifetime: yes, try older version or msvc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt 5.2.1 is unsupported as of writing this. See their issue tracker for details:

[Switch to Qt >= 5.1 #286](https://github.com/mavlink/qgroundcontrol/issues/286)

Also, if you happen to use VS2013, that is also [unsupported.](http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=oBi-nefJtSmQZZ6vakpwX3uSYOE&cid=vmBvfEjahqc&s=&fp=76893&mp&projSelected=true#L26)

Comment: OMG VS 2013 also unsupported :( ok Thank you